# UILabel > Show text (Record Saved) for a second then clear UILabel not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am working on a contacts database App. User can enter name, phone, email in UITextFields and save data to a SQLite database. All works as expected but I like to show the user a confirmation when data was successfully saved. Implemented a status label showing "Saved" when record was saved to DB but I like the text to disappear after a second.

Hope you can help, I tried to implement the `sleep()` function right after  `self.statusLabel.text = @"Saved";` but it did not work. With code below
I get the status label to say "Saved" but this should disappear automatically after a second.

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &timings) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO TIMINGS (time) VALUES (\"%@\")", self.timeLabel.text];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(timings, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
        {
            self.statusLabel.text = @"Saved";
            self.timeLabel.text = @"0:00:00";

        }
        else 
        {
            self.statusLabel.text = @"Failed";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(timings);
    }
}
```

Comment: another thing to check out is UIView + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion.  The benefit is you can have it start 1.0sec and do something cool, like have the text fade.

Comment: Coming to version 2.0 then :). Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
```

Otherwise you may consider implement a `NSTimer` that fires after a second and clean the label.

Comment: Works great and is easy to implement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Grand Central Dispatch to perform an action, like removing the label text, after a certain delay. E.g.

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.statusLabel.text = @"";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)clearLabel {
    self.statusLabel.text = @"";
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    //...
    self.statusLabel.text = @"Saved";
    [self performSelector:@selector(clearLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a easy to use view then you may use following, same as android does

https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALToastView